# Button in right side goes one line down

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website with three buttons in the top and I want them to stay on the same line, but the third one always goes down one line

```html
<div style="display: inline;" align="center">
  <div style="float: left;">
    <p style="text-align:left"><a href="Index.html" class="button">Formål</p></a>
  </div>
  <div style="float: center;">
    <p style="text-align:center"><a href="Ideer.html" class="button">Ideer</p></a>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right;">
    <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="Kontakt Os.html" class="button">Kontakt Os</p></a>
  </div>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E49wk.png)

Comment: There is no such thing as `float: center`

Answer (score 2):

Before i show you how to achieve the desired output, let me state 2 things.

1. Don't use inline CSS
2. You are complicating things by using `floats`

Using `flexbox`, you can easily achieve desired layout

```css
.btn-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}

button {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
    <button>Button 1</button>
    <button>Button 2</button>
    <button>Button 3</button>
</div>
```